# Is there anyway to create a column in a power bi matrix off other columns in that matrix?

Tags: powerbi

I have one column that i need to divide by a numeric value and place in another column on that matrix. The matrix is filled with average and counts of a large table

Comment: Add some example of what you need (sample data and desired output)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show some example data, and expected outcomes